# Fade on Checkbox for Multiple Div Sections

Tags: javascript, html

I have a client that wants to have a checkbox that says "Mark as Compete" and once marked it makes the div with content fade. They basically want a step by step list like a recipe where users can check the box when they are done with a step and have it fade out.

I have been able to do so but not in a friendly way that someone who doesn't know code would be comfortable with editing. I am looking for some help simplifying it.

Current Code:

```js
function ShowHideDivOne(chk_one) {
        var one = document.getElementById("one");
        one.style.opacity = chk_one.checked ? "0.5" : "1";
}
function ShowHideDivTwo(chk_two) {
        var two = document.getElementById("two");
        two.style.opacity = chk_two.checked ? "0.5" : "1";
}
function ShowHideDivThree(chk_three) {
        var three = document.getElementById("three");
        three.style.opacity = chk_three.checked ? "0.5" : "1";
}
```

```css
div {font-wieght:bold;font-size:30px; margin-top:30px;}
```

```html
<div id="one">One</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_one" onclick="ShowHideDivOne(this)"/>Mark as done

<div id="two">Two</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_two" onclick="ShowHideDivTwo(this)"/>Mark as done

<div id="three">Three</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_three" onclick="ShowHideDivThree(this)"/>Mark as done
```

Right now if they wanted to add a "Four," I would have to have the `ShowHideDivFour(chk_four)` function preprogrammed and then they would have to go in and change all of the `ids` and `onclicks` in the `div` and the `checkbox`.

I am ok with showing them how to edit the `id` in the `div`. What I would prefer is to have a JavaScript code that works for an unlimited number of items in their list and they would only have to change the `div` `id`. I understand if they would also have to change the `checkbox` code but it would be preferable if they didn't.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do any of the answers answer your question? If not, please update your question with more details. If yes, please consider accepting one of the answers (see gray checkmark)

Answer (score 1):

If, somehow, your headers can come after the checkboxes, you can use the CSS sibling `+` selector to select it:

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input:checked+div {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<label for="chk_one">Mark as done</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_one" />
<div id="one">One</div>

<label for="chk_two">Mark as done</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_two" />
<div id="two">Two</div>

<label for="chk_three">Mark as done</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_three" />
<div id="three">Three</div>
```

**Here is a complete, CSS-only solution** that uses the above and a little CSS flexbox hack to reverse the display order of the header and checkbox, if you're fine with wrappers:

```css
div.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /*  display elements in reverse order */
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

div.item {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

input {
  width: fit-content;
}

input:checked~div {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!--  notice that the checkboxes come BEFORE
the text, but are displayed as if they are after -->

<div class="wrapper">
  <label for="chk_one">Mark as done</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk_one" />
  <div id="one" class="item">One</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <label for="chk_two">Mark as done</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk_two" />
  <div id="two" class="item">Two</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <label for="chk_three">Mark as done</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk_three" />
  <div id="three" class="item">Three</div>
</div>
```

Any "normal" solution (not as hacky as this) would only be attainable through JavaScript.

**EDIT**: if you're OK with using JS, here's something that looks marginally better by using direct element references in inline event listeners:

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">One</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_one" onclick="one.style.opacity = (one.style.opacity == 0.5 ? 1 : 0.5)" />
<label for="chk_one">Mark as done</label>

<div id="two">Two</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_two" onclick="two.style.opacity = (two.style.opacity == 0.5 ? 1 : 0.5)" />
<label for="chk_two">Mark as done</label>

<div id="three">Three</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_three" onclick="three.style.opacity = (three.style.opacity == 0.5 ? 1 : 0.5)" />
<label for="chk_three">Mark as done</label>
```

Comment: I see what you are doing. This would be awesome but my actual div is an Elementor column. The Mark as Done checkbox can be in the same column but the items inside the column could be varied. For example, it may be elementor widgets like title, paragraph, image, paragraph, image gallery, paragraph, etc. then the checkbox. If I reversed the column the I would have to reverse all the text/images inside of it which means that it would be really tough for a blogger to edit. I apologize for not being more specific but thank you! P.S. - Don't mind using Javascript.

Comment: I see; is the updated answer something you're looking for?

Comment: Better if you can make "mark as read" also clickable. So, separate each input; in fact, checkbox text should also be working as checkbox.

Comment: @JayanikaChandrapriya I have no idea what you mean by "separate each input". Input labels are the proper way to implement "text working as checkbox" (as you said), which I have implemented.

Comment: I mean your <input> and <label> are not encircled like this
<p><input></input><label></label></p>

Comment: @JayanikaChandrapriya there is no reason to do that in the current scenario. Had we needed a text input inline with a paragraph, your code would be the proper solution; however, we don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the code by adding a class name to the checkbox and adding an event listener to all elements of that class:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.markChk').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var divID = this.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
    divID.style.opacity = el.checked ? "0.5" : "1";
  });
});
```

```css
div {font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 30px;}
```

```html
<div id="one">One</div>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="chk_one" class="markChk" /> Mark as done </label>

<div id="two">Two</div>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="chk_two" class="markChk" /> Mark as done </label>

<div id="three">Three</div>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="chk_three" class="markChk" /> Mark as done </label>
```

Notes:

- `this.parentElement.previousElementSibling` traverses from the checkbox to the previous div
- notice the `<label>`, which allows the user to click on the label, not just the checkbox
- to further simplify you likely want to generate the div and checkbox list dynamically
- jQuery makes it easier than native JS to manipulate the DOM

Comment: This may work, thank you! I would like to not have to pass the div but don't know of another way to do it.

Comment: I simplified the code further by adding a class name to the checkbox and adding an event listener to all elements of that class.